# Formatting a post HTML code gives a picture/photo in the preview

Tags: support, editor, editing-help

I have some difficulties formatting some posts which body contains HTML. The code disappear or show something else in the preview, making almost impossible to format. I didn't save but if requested I will try to find.

This issue may have been experienced by other users, but most strange thing happened today when in the preview a photo (a girl) appeared in the code preview. It was plain HTML that I was trying to format (a question). How this is possible?

Comment: You mean **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766361)**?

Comment: Wow, yes it was that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some difficulties formatting some posts which body contains HTML. The code disappear or show something else in the preview

While editing code formatting in a post, the code can temporarily be outside of a code block and the preview would then render it as is. When the code is HTML and doesn't contain a lot of visible content, as was the case with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45766361) you were [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45766361/3), it will seem as though the code disappears.

> most strange thing happened today when in the preview a photo (a girl) appeared

The `img` tag in the question's HTML uses a [placeholder image service](https://placeimg.com/) and the collection of images it can choose from contains several that show girls. I don't know which one it is you saw at the time, but if you run this code snippet enough times, you will eventually see it again.

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/400/400/bbc" alt="">
```